# Networking Phones Together in Building

Tags: electrical, wire, telephone, phone-wiring

I have a number siemens optipoint 500 economy phones.

They have been used in an office environment in which the networking of the phones were managed by a third party. I would now like to use them in my new building to allow transfer of calls to other rooms and phoning handset to handset.

I've got 1 landline coming into the building and would like any of the phones to be able to pick up the call and transfer to another phone. Luckily all the phones are in the same large room and so is the landline so I shouldn't need to do anything in the walls.

Can anyone point me to what additional hardware I need and any info on how to get this setup?

Comment: This is not the right place for this however, 1 line will not be enough you will need a minimum of 3 lines.

Comment: @sr_1436048 is incorrect about needing 3 lines: You can run a PBX with 0 outside (aka PSTN aka trunk) lines if you want. The number of trunk lines dictates how many simultaneous external calls can be handled. The smaller "key system" PBXes usually have each line accessible using a button on the phone and are a bit simpler; when you get into larger scale PBXes with more than ~8 lines this becomes unmanageable and different methods are used to handle call routing and transfers.

Comment: But I do agree, this is off-topic. @David you need a Siemens HiPath switch, and then you need to learn how to program it. You might be able to do this, or you may spend a lot more time than if you were to get a simpler system. I'd suggest you come up with criteria you need from a phone system first, and then if this system satisfies those needs you can consider using it.

Comment: @gregmac re-read the question and use common sense, how many offices do you know where no one makes any outside calls and have 1 in coming line? 3 minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a phone switch to make this work. I think these phones use a Siemens HiPath switch. The phone line from the phone company connects to the switch, then the phones connect to the switch. The switch will require detailed programming. You can probably find one cheap on eBay. However, I don't recommend this path.

Instead, I recommend buying an "expandable business phone" from some place like Office Depot. I know RCA makes a decent line, and that AT&T has a competing product but I have no experience with those. Unlike the OptiPoint phones you have, no switch is required. The phones talk to each other over the wiring you get from the phone company, but in such a way that phone company doesn't think you're making a phone call through them.

To make this work, you just have to get the phone company (or a wiring contractor) wire all of your phone lines (or just your single phone line) to every desk. Then plug the phones in. Any phone can answer any line, you can make internal calls, you can make conference calls, and you can transfer calls, just like you would with your OptiPoints.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStage and OptiPoint phones also work with a [SoftPhone system called Swyx](http://swyx.com/). However this is not a cheap solution, but I can verify that it works.

For the newer OpenStage phones, there is a SIP firmware for them, then you can connect them into any phone SIP based phone system such as Asterisk. I don't know about the OptiPoint devices as we retired them a while back.

A 10/100 Power over Ethernet switch is the easiest way to power the phones, and then you need to get a Cat5 run to where you want to mount the phones. A PoE switch ranges in price from $50 on eBay for a second hand unit up to $3,000+ for a brand new 48-port gigabit switch.

Most phone systems like this don't run off just a basic ATA (but I guess you could try it), as they require a proper trunk. An internet-based SIP trunk is not expensive. A physical ISDN trunk is expensive hardware and expensive lines that may or may not be available in your building.

All in all, there are cheaper, easier alternatives than getting a business phone solution working than something like this. An older style PABX system that has a physical switching box and analogue phones is probably easier and cheaper to implement.